# How to move kubernetes cluster to another aws zone

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes

We have a working kubernetes cluster in one zone on aws, we want to move it to another zone.

The k8s cluster is installed with the help of kops.

We don't need zero down time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance it might be done following this steps:

1. Create new cluster in the new zone
2. Deploy apps to the new cluster
3. Check everything is started successfully
4. Redirect traffic to the new cluster via switching NAT/Load Balancer/DNS
5. Shut down/Destroy old cluster

Comment: By creating a new cluster all the settings (authentication, authorization, jobs, deployments etc) are gone. The OP was about migration.

Comment: Exactly i want to avoid redeploy every thing. There is a backup function on k8s ?

Comment: It's ok, but topic starter didn't say anything about migration

Comment: Guillaume Alouege, etcd backup/restore is your case.

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple.

1. Stop all the K8S services.
2. Move the EC2 instances to the target zones as mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-ec2-instance/).
3. Start the EC2 instances in the target zones.

If an ElasticIP is used, there shouldn't be any difference to the end user except for the down time.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good solution my kops file would be misconfigured

Comment: How will be the kops be misconfigured?

Comment: off topic: can you move AWS Instances across regions?

Comment: yes - https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_Migrate_Resources_To_New_Region.pdf